# Unable to remove WindowsApps folder from previous installation

Tags: windows-10, permissions

A couple days ago I had my Windows 10 reinstalled. I decided not to format my D: drive as it contains a lot of games that I won't need to download again. Everything went fine, except, I can't install, launch nor remove old Windows Store games. I can't remove this folder with Windows settings. I tried giving myself permissions through security tab, but it didn't work with all folders. Now I can't even edit my own permissions in security tab, 2 folders can't be removed due to lack of permissions and one folder called MSIXVC contains some files that are immediately in use by SYSTEM process. I also tried removing this folder with Linux, but it told me it was read-only file system.

`Get-Acl` output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the ACL for the folder.

Comment: @Ramhound
If you mean output of `Get-Acl`, it is in post.

Comment: Edit your question, instead of providing the information, in an unformatted medium.  Screenshot would be better

Comment: @Ramhound imgur link in post

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove system attributes from the *MSIXVC* folder. Use Robocopy with the "**/s /mir**" switch to mirror the directory tree into an empty directory - I named mine as **temp_folder**.
You should now be able to remove both directories.

Run the following (in the order provided) at the command prompt as Admin:

1. mkdir **temp_folder**
2. robocopy **temp_folder** *MSIXVC* /s /mir
3. rmdir **temp_folder**
4. rmdir *MSIXVC*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Tells me the files are in usage. Here's console output https://imgur.com/a/WuzoS9C

Comment: Can you perhaps try to switch the default windows apps destination to your C:\ Drive? Go to Settings → System → Storage → Change where new content is saved. The folder is used by Microsoft Store.

Comment: The problem is, it is already set to C:\ drive. Whenever I try to set it to D:\ it tells me Windows needs to remove this folder and all of its content and after that error 0x80070020 comes out.

Comment: I would use [handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) a sysinternals utility to get the process that is locking those folders. Then kill the process. Otherwise, download Unlocker tool. It will delete the folder at next logon. Be sure not to delete the root folders required by Microsoft Store Apps otherwise it will malfunction.

Comment: Oh my god, finally. Thank you. Unlocker tool worked, it was still locked by SYSTEM itself. Still can't remove the folder due to some other error, but I can rename it and leave it there, not bothering anyone and install what I want.